# Drawing a transparent image on mouse movement with JavaScript on a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

A board game made up of SVG images is drawn in a HTML canvas. I would like to have a transparent game piece image move with the mouse while the mouse hovers over the canvas. I would like to do this without having to iterate through the game matrix every time the mouse is moved. The only method I could come up with is shown below; however, the last location of the drawn image persists, resulting in this effect:

[Draw game piece image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmeYD.png)

What is the best way to accomplish this?

```js
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", drawPieceAtMouse, false);

function drawPieceAtMouse(event) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  var x = event.clientX - rect.left;
  var y = event.clientY - rect.top;
  context.save();
  context.globalAlpha = 0.4;
  context.drawImage(players[turn].piece, x-25, y-25, 50, 50);
  context.restore();
}
```

Comment: You must use `context.clearRect` to clear the previous "cursor". To make you design more efficient you can use CSS to place a second canvas over the game canvas and just draw the "cursor" on that overlaying canvas. You can tell the 2nd canvas to not listen for mouse events with: `pointer-events:none;` so your events pass through to your game canvas below. **But perhaps a more efficient method** is to assign a custom cursor for the canvas using CSS instead of burdening the canvas with drawing at the mouse position.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", drawPieceAtMouse, false);


var canvasimg = new Image();
function updatecanvasimage(){
canvasimg = new Image();
canvasimg.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
}
updatecanvasimage()//call this when you want changes to stay on the canvas

function drawPieceAtMouse(event) {
var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var x = event.clientX - rect.left;
var y = event.clientY - rect.top;
context.drawImage(canvasimg,0 , 0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
context.globalAlpha = 0.4;
context.drawImage(players[turn].piece, x-25, y-25, 50, 50);
}
```

Comment: I receive the error "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported." A possible solution is 'var img = new Image();
img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
img.src = url;' This does not fix the error.

Comment: could I have the code for the program to do some testing